# Паттерн адаптер в Java и ислючения

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования, исключения

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь реализовать общий интерфейс для двух классов, которые возвращают однотипные данные, но при этом делают это по-своему.

Определил общий интерфейс.

```
interface BasicInterface {
    public String getName();
    public String getAddress();
}
```

Создал 2 класса, а именно: `RemoteDataAdapter` и `LocalDataAdapter`, которые реализуют интерфейс `BasicInterface`.

Как быть, если в одном из классов (RemoteDataAdapter) может быть выброшено исключение, при вызове getName(), либо getAddress(), в случае если не удалось установить соединение. В другом классе (LocalDataAdapter) метод исключений не выбрасывает.

Как унифицировать интерфейс для данного случая?

Comment: Исключение наследуется от Exception и требует обработки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариантов-то немного: либо определяете проверяемое исключение в интерфейсе, либо не определяете никаких исключений на уровне интерфейса, но выбрасываете непроверяемое.

В конце концов, если исключение и объявлено в интерфейсе, это вовсе не значит, что реализация этого интерфейса обязана его выбрасывать.